# Xamarin Forms Login Logout procedures with Web API

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to log in and get cookies in xamarin forms. At the same time, the data will remain until I log out, but when I log out, the data I keep in the cookie will be reset. how can i do it?(Actually, I can login now, but I don't understand the logic of saving the information in the cookie and logging out.)

**EDIT : I want to do it with using AppShell**

```
if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {

            var userName = tbName.Text;
            var password = tbPassword.Text;

            var serviceUrl = "API";

            var paramList = new List<ServiceParameterObject>();
            paramList.Add(new ServiceParameterObject("_userCode", userName));
            paramList.Add(new ServiceParameterObject("_userPassword", password));

            var apiResult = ApiResult.SendPostRequestFromBody(serviceUrl, paramList);



            if (apiResult.Status)
            {
                var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(apiResult.Message);

                //Preferences.Set("userName", tbName.Text);
                //Preferences.Set("Password", tbPassword.Text);
                Preferences.Set("userId", user.Id.ToString());

                var userIdCookie = Preferences.Get("userId", String.Empty);
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(HomePage)}");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Uyarı", "Kullanıcı Adınız veya Şifreniz hatalıdır. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz.", "Tamam");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Uyarı", "İnternet bağlantınız yok. Lütfen Bağlantınızı kontrol edip tekrar deneyiniz", "Tamam");
        }
```

Comment: It’s really unclear what you’re doing.  XF has no built in concept of “logged in”.  You’re free to implement that however you like.  Typically when you login to your service it returns a token that you use to validate future requests.  When you logout it invalidates the token and you would delete any local copy you have in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Have your looked into [Xamarin forms' Secure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage) ?
I think this could the easiest way for you to achieve your desired implementation.

1. Upon launch, look into storage to see if any information is stored (your cookie or any other auth information)
2. a) If Nothing is stored, run login and store information
3. b) If something is stored, grant access to app and fetch stored info
4. Upon logout, simply clear the stored cookie